# How do I get the Graphics Debugger working in Visual Studio 11?

Tags: directx, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to get the graphics debugger working using the sample code from Lesson3.Cubes of the MS [DirectX tutorial sample app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct3D-Tutorial-Sample-08667fb0) but I can't get it to work.

I've tried just pressing ALT+F5 to get the diagnostics running but when I do I get exceptions thrown in the VSGraphicsHelper.dll and the app fails to run. It works properly under the normal debugger.

I've also tried switching the debugger settings from Native to GPU debugging and when I press ALT+F5 the application runs, but the debug HUD doesn't display and I get a message: "Unable to start the experiment session" if I try and capture a frame.

For reference, I'm running the Win8 CP natively using an Intel graphics card (the NVidia drivers are still buggy and they tend to crash and log me out).

I've also looked at the question on the [requirements for the VS11 Graphics Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9696302/63179) but it didn't help me.

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to C++/DX so don't assume I know the basics. Any tips, tutorials or walkthroughs, apart from the useless MSDN articles, on how to get this working would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would love to help...

There was a bug in Beta relating to the (unrelated) "GPU" debugger setting. You should leave it set to Native. Another Beta bug to check for is whether you are running in a non-US locale. Can you turn on first-chance exceptions (Debug > Exceptions > Win32 Exceptions) and describe which exception is thrown?

Comment: Regional settings?! Genius! I would never have thought to look there.  I hope that bug is squashed before RTM.

Comment: I actually got mine to work by switching from 'Native Only' to 'Managed and Native'

Answer (score 2):

This is a project configuration issue.
To solve this issue, perform the following steps...

Go to DEBUG -> ProjectName Properties

Set 'Debugger Type' to 'Mixed (Managed and Native)' or to 'Native Only'.
Now running the Diagnostics will work correctly as intended.