# DirectX Diagnostic Mode doesn't work for Win32 ( ? )

Tags: windows, directx, direct3d

I'm working with a DirectX 11 program on Windows 8 for which I Think there is a problem with the vertex shader. I tried to start DirectX diagnostic mode ([Alt]+[F5]) and while the program will normally run without throwing an exception if diagnostic mode is turned on it will always crash at the call to "CreateSwapChainForHwnd" with the following error message

> Unhandled exception at 0x0097C004 in MyApplication.exe: 0xC0000096:
>   Privileged instruction.

Does DirectX debugging simply not work for Windows Storeapplications? It seems to work fine in specific Win32 application scenarios, but I seem to be encountering many scenarios where it doesn't work.

Update:

Among other things I installed the DirectX debugging symbols and got a marginally more detailed message.

> Unhandled exception at 0x000007FDED063589 (dxgi.dll) in
>   MyApplication.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x0000000000000000.

So it looks to be a null reference exception from the code on Microsoft's end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the debugger doesn't like CreateSwapChainForHwnd(), as this other guy found out: [Requirements for target application for Visual Studio 11's Graphics Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696302/requirements-for-target-application-for-visual-studio-11s-graphics-debugger)

My code calls D3D11CreateDevice() followed by IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain() and the debugger works for desktop win32 apps, so try that.

What are the specific Windows Store application scenarios that you got it to work in? I have the exact opposite problem - I cant get Alt-F5 debugger to work at all for windows store apps, but it works for desktop win32 apps.